# Combine many xml files into one big file

Tags: xml, windows, doxygen

I am trying to sent Doxygen xml output to graphviz but I have over 1000+ xml files to be combined and I do not know how to do this on windows. I have Saxon installed for the XSLT processing once it is all in one file, but I don't know how to combine the files.

My pipeline as I understand it will go like this:

> Doxygen XML output -> Merge to single XML (how) -> XSLT process via Saxon -> Convert to DOT -> output via graphviz -> Party

Doxygen has output the XML, I have a command for using saxon after merging `java -jar c:\saxon\saxon9he.jar -s:myinput.xml -xsl:myxslt.xslt -o:myoutput.xml`, and there are endless utilities for DOT conversion. **But how do you merge hundreds of XML files?**

I can run batch files/scripts or python scripts or commands of windows programs as a solution. I'm looking for something that works in a continuous pipeline for future use of another set of possibly several hundred files. My ultimate goal is to print out the large chart created from graphviz as an alternate to UML mapping which was hard enough to find a solution for (Doxygen is reading C code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the XPath `collection()` function. You can either do the merging in a separate step in your pipeline as you suggest, or you can incorporate it into your main stylesheet. For example:

```
<xsl:variable name="merged">
  <xsl:copy-of select="collection('file:///c:/data/dir/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: As it turns out, I can't read. I had read in the Doxygen manual that `If you prefer one big XML file you can combine the index and the other files using the XSLT file combine.xslt` but didn't know how. Reading what you wrote made me wonder why they didn't have that and they do in said file. They also have `If you have xsltproc you could use:
     xsltproc combine.xslt index.xml >all.xml` in that file so I have run it in the Saxon command I previously posted. I have some file encoding errors to fix and then I can test it fully.

Comment: Single file looks ok, now I'm looking at converting to DotML so I can get a graph into graphviz.